# Is there a prestige class that grants Turn Undead/Rebuke Undead?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, pathfinder-1e, dnd-3e, prestige-class

Is there a prestige class in D&D 3.x or Pathfinder which, at first level, grants Turn Undead or Rebuke Undead if you don't already have it?

I'm using Arcanist/Rainbow Servant. I need Turn/Rebuke undead to enter Radient Servant of Pelor, and I would rather take a Prestige class that increases my current caster level than take a level of Cleric...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**For a rainbow servant into radiant servant of the burning hate, a 1 level sacred exorcist dip is your best bet.**

The comprehensive [forum post by widow](http://brilliantgameologists.com/boards/index.php?topic=11345.msg388436#msg388436) says:

grants turn/rebuke undead - anything that grants turning generally stacks

> - Cleric 1
> - Paladin 4
> - Blackguard 3, ecl, command or rebuke only
> - Sacred Exorcist 1, ecl 8, Complete Divine, turn only
> - Ur-priest 2, ecl 7, Complete Divine, rebuke only
> - Divine Mind 4, Complete Divine, class variant (here)
> - Dread Necromancer 1, base class, Heroes of Horror, rebuke only
> - Death Delver 1, ecl 6, Heroes of Horror, rebuke only
> - Chameleon 3, ecl 8, Races of Destiny, see text
> - Master of Radiance 1, ecl 6, Libris Mortin, turn only - unclear whether you gain turning or if it only stacks
> - Tenebrous, vestige, ecl 7, Tome of Magic, unlimited use but see text
> - Knight of the Raven 3, ecl 7, Expedition to Castle Ravenloft
> - Apostle of Peace 1, ecl 8, Book of Exalted Deeds
> - Soldier of Light 1, ecl 6, Deities and Demigods
> - Deadgrim 1, ecl 6, Magic of Eberron - unclear whethero you gain turning or if it only stacks

levels stack for turn/rebuke undead (ie: requires turn/rebuke to qualify for the PrC)

> - Radiant Servant of Pelor, ecl 7, Complete Divine
> - Warpriest, ecl 6, Complete Divine
> - Eldritch Disciple, ecl 6, Complete Mage
> - Paragnostic Apostle, ecl 3?, Complete Champion
> - Ordained Champion, ecl 4, Complete Champion
> - Master of Shrouds, ecl 4, Libris Mortis - rebuke only
> - Sacred Purifier, Libris Mortis - turn only
> - True Necromancer, Libris Mortis - rebuke only
> - Purifier of the Hallowed Doctrine, ecl 6, Heroes of Horror - turn only
> - Death Delver, ecl 6, Heroes of Horror, rebuke only
> - Bone Knight, ecl 5, Eberron Five Nations, rebuke only
> - Deadgrim, ecl 6, Magic of Eberron
> - Eye of Horus-Re 1, ecl 7, Player's Guide to Faerun

Comment: you forgot the Binder class, which can get a binding that allows for a rebuke that lvls, found in the Tome of Magic. ecl 6, I think?